# How to link a duplicated target name

Tags: cmake

I have a third part project which consumes a library with same executable name:

```
add_executable(foo main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(foo foo)
```

The application name is *foo*, but the library, which is imported, also have the same name.

I thought in just renaming the output, but the application target name is re-used in many places to generate a cmake target file.

Is there some trick that I could use to solve the library name, like an alias?

Comment: You need to have **different target names** for executables and libraries in your project. Note, that *target name* doesn't enforce the name of the *executable file*. You may change executable *filename* by setting [OUTPUT_NAME](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/prop_tgt/OUTPUT_NAME.html) of the executable *target*.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I think OUTPUT_NAME is the only way. Even using ALIAS is not possible to link.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Tsyvarev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3440745/tsyvarev), the best option could be renaming the output.